# HTML5 video should fadeOut on end

Tags: jquery, html, video

the problem is that the video doesnt fade out on several windows machines with firefox. I know that I have 2 ways implemented so that it should work....but it sadly doesnt.
On those machines where it does not work, the DivX-Logo and the DivX-Player timeline shows. Probably this is the problem why it does not work?

my code:

> ```
>  <div id="video">
>     <video id="vid" autoplay preload="auto">
>      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" width="100%"type="video/mp4" ></source>
>   </video> 
> </div>
> ```

```
video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                    $('#vid').addClass('hide');
                    $('video').delay(100).fadeOut();

                }, false);
                video.play();
```

I have a little jsfiddle for you:
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DSteinel/4YGqJ/2/)

thanks in advance!

Comment: You are adding a class of `hide` before fading out. Maybe that?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the Divx plugin. Note that Firefox does not support mp4 format without a plugin. Consider adding an alternate source for Firefox in Ogg Vorbis or WebM?